Did any Famicom game use microphone for random seed?
So I know most common way to generate pseudo-random numbers on Famicom or NES is linear feedback shift-register.
However... It came to my mind - Famicom controller has a microphone. Did any game ever implement to instead do RNG by sampling noise from the microphone input? If not, would it be possible?

I don't think that the famicom controller had a microphone in it. Are you sure about that?

@OmarandLorraine - The Famicom’s Built-In Microphone Was Wonderfully Weird

I can't see why it wouldn't be possible; if you used a maximal polynomial for the LFSR size and checked you weren't seeding it with the one remaining illegal state.

The second question of your two is just a 'what if' that applies to any system with a microphone in it, not just retro systems. Yes, it's possible but lots of things are possible. That's much more a discussion forum question rather than suited for a Q&A site.

@TonyM juding by the top answer, it is actually not possible on the Famicom, because the microphone only produces 1 bit of data (noise present/absent). So it is a valid Q&A question in that regard.

@ChrisWarrick, my point is valid, I can only assume you're not familiar with RNGs or serial data. A RNG gets long sequences of bits from a single random noise source by reading bits successively at intervals, then putting them together into a single binary value. That's basic computing and has already been said below. It also applies to anything with a mic input, not just Famicon. Hence my point.

The whole idea of ​​a mic on retrocomputing sounds futuristic, this overlaps the time really because some of other retro machines (not consoles) used them (you can record a 1-bit voice on ZX-Spectrum for example). But I never seen anything on piracy copies of Famicom/NES from China which was in my childhood in ex-USSR, also in all NES roms collection later.

But if you mean mic for generating random data there a lot of ways to get them from any counters or a byte from memory by pointed by this counter. It's more cheaper for CPU than use hardware sampling of 1-bit data. I don't know a deeper an architecture of CPU on NES, but you can take a look at register R at Zilog Z80. I believe the same ways is possible on NES/Famicom.

There are no documented games that used the mic for RNG. Hardly any games used the mic at all, and the mic was so unpopular it was dropped in later versions of the Famicom. As far as I can tell, there's not even ten games that used the mic. The mic is also unsuitable as a hardware entropy source, as it provides a simple 1-bit signal for the audio. That's right, it's basically an acoustically operated button. If a game wanted hardware entropy, it would have been much easier to just use the player's inputs as the source, because then you'd have 8 bits of entropy to use. However, most, if not all, developers either used a deterministic (e.g. frame counter) or a LFSR algorithm. Even if a modern developer from today were to write a new game for the Famicom, they'd likely use a LFSR, as they were cheap to implement on hardware that doesn't have many spare clock cycles.

but you could also read the microphone several times to get more bits.

@Jean-FrançoisFabre unless the user was actively dumping audio into the mic, they'd all be zeroes. According to various forums, there's a lowpass filter on the mic, and you also have to be actively trying to trigger the mic (audio at a close distance or loud dB) to register 1 bits. It'd be a fun gimmick to implement, but the player would need to know it's even a feature to intentionally try RNG manipulation using this hardware setup.

So in a way it was the original "Nintendo gimmick nobody found a good use for", right before ROB, forced touch controls on DS and forced 3D on 3DS? Cool, lmfao
